# Create a stand alone exe from VS2015 solution coded in C#

Tags: exe, app-config

I have a solution developed in VS2015 coded in C#. I want it to be used by other colleagues too. How can i accomplish this since i have an app.config file, which has pathnames to some files which are required for performing my functionalities. Is it possible to embedd the config file and change later depending on the filepath in the colleagues' computer? Hope my question is clear!

Comment: You could have application settings as a default, and over-ride them with user settings when required. [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings).

Comment: My solution actually opens an application as a part of the functionality and does some calculations and stores results in a file. So the path for the installed exe of that application might be different for each person. So is it possible to acheive through ApplicationSettings and User Settings?

Comment: Yes, you could, for example, have a settings form in your program where the user can browse for and set the path. Save that in the user setttings.

Comment: Thats cool...will surely try it right now! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: So i tried somethings and just came across a solutionas to open a file dialog and browse to the folder, which i found interesting. and it looks fine in my system. So how do i test if the solution works appropriately in another computer? I tried running the .exe but it failed and threw some errors!! :(

Comment: Did you copy *all* the contents of the "release" (or "debug", if you're creating a debug build) directory to the other computer to test it? Please note that we can't see what the errors are unless you tell us.

Comment: Yes i have some filepath in the solution creating the errors.I want to write logs for my project.I tried to specify the location which is not a good method as seen;so i have tried to add in config file:
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="application.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics> 
But i cannot find the logs unless i run the VS solution.Running the exe does not create the log.